# Why am I getting an EOF Exception in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote the following method to read a file, search for a certain character "$", and return a boolean indicating whether it is present or not. For some reason, I keep getting a EOFException at line 224, where it simply says "s = raf.readUTF". All I'm doing is reading the records and adding them to an array list. Here is the code:

```
    public boolean buildComparisonArray(String passedPath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    ArrayList<String> comparisonArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean unwantPresent = false;
    File file = new File(passedPath);
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    raf.seek(0);
    long num = 0;
    long fileSize = 0;
    int record = 0;
    fileSize = raf.length();
        record = 160;
        num = fileSize/record;
        String s = "", s2 = "", s3="",s4="",s5="",s6="",s7="",s8="";
    long currentPositionOfFilePointer;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
            currentPositionOfFilePointer = raf.getFilePointer();
            System.out.println("Current: "+currentPositionOfFilePointer);
            s = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s.length();j++){
                raf.readByte();
            }
            s2 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s2);
             System.out.println("Found in file: "+s2);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            } 
            s3 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s3);
             System.out.println("Found in file: "+s3);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }
            s4 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s4);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s4);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }
            s5 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s5);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s5);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }
            s6 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s6);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s6);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }
            s7 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s7);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s7);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }

            s8 = raf.readUTF();
            comparisonArray.add(s8);
            System.out.println("Found in file: "+s8);
            for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
               raf.readByte();
            }
        }
    raf.close();
    for(String j: comparisonArray){
        if(j.contains("$")){
            unwantPresent = true;
        }else if(!j.contains("$")){
            unwantPresent = false;
        }
    }
    return unwantPresent;
}
```

All i'm trying to do is read through a random access file of one line and check whether or not the "$" symbol is present.

Comment: Well were the files *written* using `RandomAccessFile.writeUTF`?

Comment: Yes they were written using writeUTF

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example which writes the file and then reads it? You shouldn't need as much code as you've presented here - *just* enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: public void writeFile(String path, ArrayList<String> array){
 boolean present = true;
 present = buildComparisonArray(path);
 if(present=false){
  RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path,"rw");
  int size = array.size();
  for(Iterator<String> it = array.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
     String str = it.next();
     if(!str.contains("$")){
      file.writeUTF(str);
         for(int i=0; i<20-str.length(); i++){
          file.writeByte(20);
         }
     }else if(str.contains("$")){
      //do stuff
                writeFile(path, newArray);
     }

Comment: ah shoot I forgot comments don't format code.

Comment: It shouldn't be in a comment anyway - it should be in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read s2 u forgot to change s2 to s3, s2 to s4 and so on in your for-instruction

```
s2 = raf.readUTF();
comparisonArray.add(s2);
 System.out.println("Found in file: "+s2);
for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
   raf.readByte();
} 
s3 = raf.readUTF();
comparisonArray.add(s3);
 System.out.println("Found in file: "+s3);
for(int j=0; j<20-s2.length();j++){
   raf.readByte();
}
```

Comment: I changed it but for some reason I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I noticed in your writeFile(...) u wrote "if (present = false)" wich caused it to skip regardless of value. Also to shorten the code you can just use "for (String str : array) {" to iterate trough the ArrayList. I tried the code and it worked for me while i used your writeFile()...

Comment: So you're saying that I need to change the if statement?

Comment: You should but I don't know for sure if it will fix your problem... Since you flagged my answer as correct I guess it did it. If you really just want to check for an $ there is probably a simpler method...